# What is the purpose of Services in Angular?

Tags: angular

I don't really understand the concept of Service in Angular, Is it like the "Model" in the MVC concept? I'm coming from C++\Java background and never had any experience with web-development and just started learning Angular 4 couple days ago.

I would really appreciate if someone could clear this for me.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you're learning Angular, you should probably take a look to the documentation first : [**Angular Archirtecture**](https://angular.io/guide/architecture). There's a whole explanation about services in Angular.

Answer (score 1):

Services are basically classes that can be called from other Components / Directives / Services. In terms of OOPS it is a form of `Association`, usually `Aggregation`. For example if you have to allow user login from multiple places i.e header, footer, in case of e-commerce site when user tries to add a product to cart etc... Then you would not want to have different functions for same functions, instead what you want is one method in a class that can be called from other classes. Below is example code to show it's usage:

header.component.ts:

```
login() {
    this.commonService.loginUser()
}
```

footer.component.ts :

```
login() {
    this.commonService.loginUser()
}
```

common.service.ts :

```
loginUser() {
    // custom code for loggin in user
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want really understand the concept of a service in Angular application, then you need to know about the **singleton design pattern** first.

Answer (score 0):

Angular js is a framework. It has all the concept required to build a website using best practices. Role of service in the angular app is to write logics and code that not for model binding between view and controller. In simple, controller are supposed to only get used for model binding so you write logic in service. This helps you to make your code reusable and clean.

Comment: So, if I'm developing tic-tac-toe SPA, then the logic of the game should be implemented inside the service, am I right?